# RSpec: Factory Girl view test generates a "undefined method" error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I have a page at orders/edit.html.erb that I'm testing with the following code:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "orders/edit.html.erb" do
  before(:each) do
    @order = FactoryGirl.create(:order)
    #assign(:order, stub_model(Order,
    #  :new_record? => false,
    #  :email => "MyString",
    #  :name => "MyString"
    #))
  end

  it "renders the edit order form" do
    render :template => "orders/edit", :handlers => [:erb]

  end
end
```

However, I am getting the following test failure error message:

```
orders/edit.html.erb renders the edit order form
     Failure/Error: render :template => "admin/fulfillment/orders/edit", :handlers => [:erb]
     ActionView::Template::Error:
       undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
```

Here is where the conflict happens in orders/edit.html.erb:

```
<h3>New Order # <%= @order.number %></h3>
<legend>
  <% if @order.user.name && @order.user.waiter.name %>
  Diner: <%= @order.user.name %> / Waiter: <%= @order.user.waiter.name %>
  <% else %>
  No Name available <% end %>
</legend>
<div class="row">
...
```

**Update: here is my factories/order.rb - am I not generating enough User data as well, triggering the nil?**

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  sequence :number do |n|
    n
  end

      factory :order do
        number          #{ Factory.next(:number) }
        email           'email@e.com'
        state           'in_progress'
        user            { |c| c.association(:user) }
        bill_address_id    { |c| c.association(:address).id }
        ship_address_id    { |c| c.association(:address).id }
        active          true
        calculated_at   Time.now
        completed_at    Time.now

        after_build {|oi| oi.send(:initialize_state_machines, :dynamic => :force)}
      end
      factory :in_progress_order, :parent => :order do
        state           'in_progress'
      end

      factory :complete_order, :parent => :order do
        state           'complete'
      end
```

What am I doing wrong with the test and what do I need to do to get it to pass?

Comment: can we see your factories.rb?

Comment: Please also add the Orders controller with the edit action

Comment: Check out the Law of Demeter for some cool refactoring around your @order.user.name calls - http://rails-bestpractices.com/posts/15-the-law-of-demeter

Answer (score 0):

Your test is failing because `@order.user.stylist` is `nil`. In your `if` statement, you check for `@order.user.name` and `@order.user.waiter.name`, but you do not check for `@order.user.stylist.name`.

Try this.

```
<h3>New Order # <%= @order.number %></h3>
<legend>
  <% if @order.user.name && @order.user.waiter.name && @order.user.stylist.name %>
    Diner: <%= @order.user.name %> / Waiter: <%= @order.user.stylist.name %>
  <% else %>
     No Name available 
  <% end %>
</legend>
<div class="row">
...
```

Comment: sorry - that was a typo on my part. my code actually does have "waiter", I was just playing around with a model. I've edited and provided the correct erb code above.

Comment: @mztwo What line does `undefined method name for nil:NilClass` error point at?

Comment: It's pointing at order.user.name and order.user.waiter.name.

So I've identified the issue: it's because I'm attempting to call order.user.waiter whereas the factory for order.rb is only generating a user for the order.  Thus the nil.

How do I add the user.waiter to the Factory?